# Luke 5:17 where is the power?

Tags: greek, grammar, language

Looking at Luke 5:17
some of the translations will read: "And the power of the Lord was present to heal/for healing", while others will read: "And the power of the Lord was with him (Jesus) to heal/for healing".

So how should one translate the Greek words kai dunamis kuriou ēn eis to iasthai auton, and why so?

And do these words in the Greek indicate that this power of the Lord was in him, working through him or that it was at work there; i.e. it was active around Jesus, among the people, outside of Jesus. **strong text**

Comment: The literal (EGNT/Stephens 1550) is _and power of Lord was unto ( eis ) to heal them_ . No problem. It is the W&H/Nestle insistence on the singular _auton_ that causes the problem. The power  of the Lord was present to heal the Pharisees and teachers of the law. _But they would not be healed._ [Up-voted +1.]

Answer (score 1):

It is an awkward way to put a fairly simple fact.

This awkwardness gave rise to textual variations in an attempt to make it easier.

Let's put it in context.

1. He was teaching one day to pharisees scribes from all the towns of Galilee, Judah and Jerusalem.

(17 last part) And the lord had power for him to heal.

People brought a cripple to him but they couldn't get to Jesus, because of the crowd (he was teaching to a lot of people), so they climbed up on the roof and lowered him down to Jesus (18-19)

20 Jesus saw his faith and said "Man, your sins are forgiven."

This upset the pharisees and scribes. (21) To them, Jesus asks "What is easier, to forgive sins or to say "Get up and walk."? (23)

Now the passage you ask for:

> καὶ δύναμις Κυρίου ἦν εἰς τὸ ἰᾶσθαι αὐτόν = and power of [the] Lord was for(in) him to heal.

The subject of the main clause is δύναμις (power), it is the lord's power (δύναμις Κυρίου) and its purpose (εἰς τὸ + infinitive) is for him to heal (εἰς τὸ ἰᾶσθαι αὐτόν).

Now in an infinitive construction, if the subject is expressed, it is put into the accusative (αὐτόν), him. This is always the normal case when the subject of the infinitive construction is not the same as the governing clause (δύναμις), power in this case. (BDF §406 "The infinitive with a subject accusative".)

(There are situations where the infinitive can have a subject in the nominative case, but is when the subject of the governing clause and the subject of the infinitive are the same.)

This is not the first time this sentence has caused trouble. As has already been pointed out, there were others who did not understand this, and tried to supply objects to the infinitive construction, εἰς τὸ ἰᾶσθαι (in order to heal). The existing αὐτόν (him, subject) was not understood and does not fit the context as an object, so they supplied: αὐτούς (them), πάντας (all), αὐτοὺς πάντας (all of them).

But look at the context. Jesus was not there to heal at that moment, he was there teaching.

Beginning of verse 17: καὶ αὐτὸς ἦν διδάσκων (and he was teaching) not healing. He was teaching them, not healing them.

But we get a bit of information to prepare us for the continuation in verse 23.

A decent English translation, and an accurate one, would be: The lord had the power to heal.

But it doesn't sound as "Biblical" and the phrasing of this sentence is, what can I say, stylistically solemn.

Answer (score 0):

The Greek sentence in Luke 5:17 reads (NA28/UBS5 etc):

> καὶ δύναμις Κυρίου ἦν εἰς τὸ ἰᾶσθαι αὐτόν = (literally) and power of
> [the] Lord was for(in) to heal him.

Let is observe several features of the grammatical structure:

αὐτόν = "him" here is accusative and thus is either object of the verb "to heal" (unlikely because there is no antecedent) or the preposition εἰς = into, in, for.  This latter is the obvious choice because it gives the pronoun "him" an antecedent of "Lord".  Thus, we could translate the sentence as either:

- and the power of [the] Lord was [there/present] for Him to heal, or
- and the power of [the] Lord was in Him to heal.

Both are grammatically possible and both are theologically acceptable but convey a slightly different message.  However, there is a text dispute as well and thus we have the Byzantine text as:

> καὶ δύναμις κυρίου ἦν εἰς τὸ ἰᾶσθαι αὐτούς = (literally) and power of
> the [the] Lord was for to heal them.

Note that with the plural pronoun, "them" must be the object of the verb "to heal".  Thus we translate more idiomatically:

> and the power of the Lord was [present] to heal them.

The more "difficult and interesting" question is who is the "Lord" here - is it Jesus or the Father?  Normally, when unspecified, "Lord" usually refers to Jesus but not universally.  However, this is the subject of another question.

**CONCLUSION:**

If we accept the NA28/UBS5 text then we have:

- and the power of the Lord was present for Him to heal.  This means that Jesus power was available for healing.

If we accept the Byzantine text then we have:

- and the power of the Lord was present to heal them.  This could mean that God's power was available for Jesus to heal or that Jesus' power was present for Him to heal.

**APPENDIX - Textual Problem**

In Bruce Metzger's "Textual Commentary on the GNT" he records:

> The failure to see that αὐτόν is the subject, not the object of τὸ
> ἰᾶσθαι led copyists to replace it with a plural form, as αὐτούς (A C D
> al), ...

Comment: I would take the αὐτόν as the accusative subject to the infinitive ἰᾶσθαι. The εἰς τὸ + infinitive construction is widely used. B-D-F §391(3) "result", §402(2) "cause, result" much like τοῦ + inf and §406 "The infinitive with a subject accusative". "The lord had the power to heal".

Comment: @DanielRidings - then you end up with the result: "and the power of the Lord was present to heal him".  Who is the "him" here?

Comment: I should have been a little more verbose. I took αὐτόν to be the lord. "The lord had the power for the lord to heal." αὐτόν is not the object of ἰᾶσθαι, but the subject. Since the subject of the infinitive, in Greek, is not the same subject as the main clause δύναμις, it needs to be expressed. Superfluous in English, since "the lord" is the subject of our translation. In bad English "There was a power of the lord, for him to heal."

Comment: to adjust your translation in your reply to me (not the one in your answer): "and the power of the lord was present for him to heal."

Comment: @DanielRidings The literal (EGNT/Stephens 1550) is _and power of Lord was unto ( eis_ ) _to heal them_ . No problem. It is the W&H/Nestle insistence on the singular _auton_ that causes the problem.

Comment: Well, @NigelJ I have to admit, that I only read the NT in Greek, so I am not familiar with the translations. The "heal them" is a slight problem here (and arose because of a change in the text, see my answer) ... slight problem here, because at this point he was teaching (see beginning of v 17) not healing.